# Issues with netty dns resolver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to run a spring boot application. It is trying to make a request to an API but it always return DNS not resolved. Following is the error i am getting the first time it starts up is :

```
2024-01-04T01:37:07.843+05:30 ERROR 2593 --- [           main]     
i.n.r.d.DnsServerAddressStreamProviders  : Unable to load 
io.netty.resolver.dns.macos.MacOSDnsServerAddressStreamProvider, 
fallback to system defaults. This may result in incorrect DNS 
resolutions on MacOS. Check whether you have a dependency on 
'io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos'. Use DEBUG level to see 
the full stack: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: failed to load the 
required native library
```

I add the dependency in the pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-resolver-dns-native-macos</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.104.Final</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

And then i am getting the following error

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    io.netty.util.AsciiString.<init>(AsciiString.java:225)

The following method did not exist:

    'byte[] io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent.allocateUninitializedArray(int)'

The calling method's class, io.netty.util.AsciiString, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/Users/arshdeep/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.104.Final/netty-common-4.1.104.Final.jar!/io/netty/util/AsciiString.class

The called method's class, io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/arshdeep/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-all/5.0.0.Alpha2/netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha2.jar!/io/netty/util/internal/PlatformDependent.class
    jar:file:/Users/arshdeep/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-common/4.1.104.Final/netty-common-4.1.104.Final.jar!/io/netty/util/internal/PlatformDependent.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent: file:/Users/arshdeep/.m2/repository/io/netty/netty-all/5.0.0.Alpha2/netty-all-5.0.0.Alpha2.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes io.netty.util.AsciiString and io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent
```

It should print a random quote or something when it runs the service that is calling the api is as follows :

```
public void fetchData(){
        String url = "https://andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.rapidapi.com";
        String response = webClient.get()
                .uri(url)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String.class)
                .block();
        // Process the response
        System.out.println(response);
}
```

Here i have built the header :

```
 WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder = WebClient.builder();
  webClientBuilder.defaultHeader("X-RapidAPI Key","9dff9c8f00mshb7ecdf7a126650ep1def5ejsn792bdbdeb119")
                .defaultHeader("Accept","application/json")
                .defaultHeader("Connection","keep-alive")
                .defaultHeader("X-RapidAPI-Host","andruxnet-random-famous-quotes.p.rapidapi.com");
MyService service = new MyService(webClientBuilder);
```